# Accessing Windows VMs on XenServer with Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, xenserver

I've installed XenServer 7.6 on a dedicated server and connected to internet via static public IP address given by technical support where I bought the server from.

Using XenCenter I have also installed Windows Server 2016 and Windows 7 as VMs. At first because i am newbie I had problems connecting Windows Server 2016 and Windows 7 on internet, but I fixed that using 2 other static public IP addresses given by the technical support and I set to those two VMs.
Is there a way connecting VMs on internet without these IP addresses? Something like using the IP address of the XenServer with some port that would redirect to the particular VM? For example, 185.85.214.245:3389

Now, I have installed Hyper-V on Windows Server 2016 and there I plan to install Windows Server 2012. Can I access that Windows Server 2012 using Remote Desktop Connection?

I plan to do something like this:
XenServer -> Windows Server 2016 -> Hyper-V on Windows Server 2016 -> Windows Server 2012 (internet connection and remote desktop connection)

Comment: Teamviewer ? or such tool

Comment: Remote Desktop Connection by Windows OS, because it's easier for newbies to connect to VMs and test

Answer (score 1):

You need a particular IP of the VM or DNS name (if joined to the domain) to connect via RDP. In theory, you can configure port forwarding from Win2016 IP to Win2012R2 IP on another port.

for example to access Win2016 he needs to use:

192.168.55.55:3389

to access Win2012R2 VM with port forwarding:

192.168.55.55:3390

Same IP but different ports. (Port forwarding needs to be configured on the switch)